# What is the complement of empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have learned that for universal set $U$ and  for set $A$ belonging to $U$,
$A^c=U-A$ but what about for the empty set?

Comment: The complement of $A$ contains everything in $U$ that is not in $A. \qquad$

Comment: Every thing that is not in the empty set is .... everything.  And by your formula $\emptyset^c = U - \emptyset = U$.

Answer (score 4):

The complement of the empty set would be $U$. Using your formula:

$\emptyset^C = U - \emptyset = U$

Also, the complement of $U$ is the empty set: $U^C = U - U = \emptyset$

Comment: Complement of empty set is the whole set?

Comment: @ReshamBashyal Correct!

Comment: @Resham Bashyal I am puzzled that you are ... puzzled with that. What were you thinking at first ?

Comment: What if $U=\emptyset$? Do we have $\emptyset^c=\emptyset$?

Comment: @samwolfe Correct!

Answer (score 2):

But U will still contain the empty set, since all sets contain it. It seems nonsensical to talk about U without the null set, since the complement set still contains it. Help.